# DAX Average of datediff with condition

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a very common business use case which I handled in M/Power Query but I'm struggling to efficiently process it in Dax.

I have a list of Jira tickets with start and end dates. I want to know for every month how many Jira tickets were opened and what the average ticket age was at this point in time.

For instance, a ticket is opened in March and closed in April, so it should count as open in March with an age on 1 month, April with an age of 2 months and it should not appear any longer in the calculation from May on.

The final output will be a time-series with the months in x-axis and the average ticket lifetime and the number of tickets in y-axis.

Would you have any clue wrt how to process this business case please ?

Thanks in advance,

Nicolas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you have a table named `Ticket` with the following:

| Ticket ID | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12/03/2023 | 20/04/2023 |
| 2 | 15/03/2023 | 29/04/2023 |
| 3 | 05/03/2023 | 05/05/2023 |
| 4 | 08/06/2023 | 20/07/2023 |
| 5 | 13/06/2023 | 09/08/2023 |
| 6 | 18/06/2023 | 16/07/2023 |
| 7 | 23/06/2023 | 20/07/2023 |
| 8 | 28/06/2023 | 31/07/2023 |
| 9 | 03/07/2023 | 31/07/2023 |
| 10 | 08/07/2023 | 25/08/2023 |
| 11 | 13/07/2023 | 16/08/2023 |
| 12 | 18/07/2023 | 12/09/2023 |
| 13 | 23/07/2023 | 22/08/2023 |
| 14 | 28/07/2023 | 02/09/2023 |
| 15 | 02/08/2023 | 21/09/2023 |
| 16 | 07/08/2023 | 14/09/2023 |
| 17 | 12/08/2023 | 17/09/2023 |
| 18 | 17/08/2023 | 28/09/2023 |
| 19 | 22/08/2023 | 09/10/2023 |
| 20 | 27/08/2023 | 27/10/2023 |
| 21 | 25/08/2023 |  |
| 22 | 05/11/2023 |  |

And that you have a date table named `Dim Date`. As an example:

```
Dim Date = SUMMARIZE(
  CALENDAR( DATE(2023, 1, 1), DATE(2023, 12, 31) ),
  [Date],
  "Month Year", FORMAT([Date], "MMM 'yy"),
  "Month Year sort", Year([Date]) * 12 + MONTH([Date]),
  "Year", Year([Date]),
  "Month", FORMAT([Date], "MMM"),
  "Month Num", MONTH([Date])
)
```

It is assumed there is **no relationship** between `Dim Date` and `Ticket` tables.

Then you can create the following three Measures (in this order):

```
# Ticket count = 
  CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT('Ticket'[Ticket ID]),
    'Ticket'[Start Date] <= MAX('Dim Date'[Date]) &&
    COALESCE( 'Ticket'[End Date], TODAY() ) >= MIN('Dim Date'[Date])
  )


# Ticket age = 
  var dStart = SELECTEDVALUE('Ticket'[Start Date])
  var dEnd = MIN(
    COALESCE(SELECTEDVALUE('Ticket'[End Date]), TODAY()),
    MAX('Dim Date'[Date])
  )
  RETURN IF([# Ticket count] > 0, DATEDIFF(dStart, dEnd, DAY) )
  // if you want monthly age then use...
  // RETURN IF([# Ticket count] > 0, DATEDIFF(dStart, dEnd, MONTH) + 1 )


AVG Ticket age = 
  AVERAGEX(
    FILTER(VALUES('Ticket'[Ticket ID]), [# Ticket count] > 0),
    [# Ticket age]
  )
```

And that should get you to where you want to be.

[image]

Comment: Sam, it worked like a charm! Still trying to understand why my attempts didn't work out tho...

Comment: Great, please Accept the answer for the benefit of all. And next time, share the code you have tried so that we help highlight the issue and resolution.